# Elastic search runs groovy scripts two times, is it a bug?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I found some unexpected behaviour with script query (script is executing two times in a simple query).

My configuration: elastic search version: 2.4.6 (issue remains in elastic 5.6)

My elasticsearch.yml:

```
script.indexed: true
```

The steps to reproduce the issue:

1) I have one simple document, doc1.json:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "tags": "t1"
}
```

2) Insert doc1 in Elastic:

http PUT localhost:9200/default/type1/1 @doc1.json

3) I have one simple groovy script, script1.json (just returns the score and print it):

```
{
     "script": "println('Score is ' + _score * 1.0 + ' for document ' + doc['id'] + ' at ' + DateTime.now().getMillis()); return _score;"
}
```

4) Register script1:

http POST 'localhost:9200/_scripts/groovy/script1' @script1.json

5) Execute this query_with_script.json:

```
{
   "query":{
      "function_score":{
         "query":{
            "bool":{
               "must":{
                  "match":{
                     "tags":{
                        "query":"t1",
                        "type":"boolean"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         "functions":[
            {
               "script_score":{
                  "script":{
                     "id":"script1",
                     "lang":"groovy"
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "boost_mode":"replace"
      }
   },
   "explain" : true
}
```

http GET 'localhost:9200/default/type1/_search' @query_with_script.json

6) Why in Elastic search logs I see that the script is executed in two different times? Is it a bug?

```
Score is 0.19178301095962524 for document [1] at 1516586818596
Score is 0.19178301095962524 for document [1] at 1516586818606
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you remove the explain flag?

Comment: It was that. If you want you can put it as answer and I will mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably remove the explain flag as it might be the reason why the script gets executed twice.